How to use FPGA system clock for my design in vivado?
Problem is my device don't use system clock generator (what me need) for synchronization,but use clock signal is generated by TestBench what connected via external I/O ports of FPGA.
I have description on Verilog of device what cosists of Moore machine and data path in one module.
Device description on Verilog
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module specialized_digital_device(d1, d2, reset, clkKA, clkOA, x, oA, oB, oS1, oS2, oS3, state);

input [7:0] d1, d2; 
input reset, clkKA, clkOA;

output x; 
output [7:0] oA, oB, oS1, oS2, oS3; 
output [3:0] state;

reg [7:0] A, B, S1, S2, S3;   

    //для перегляду вмісту регістрів
assign x = A<=25; 
assign oA = A;
assign oB = B;
assign oS1 = S1;
assign oS2 = S2;
assign oS3 = S3;

assign x = A<=25;
wire [19:0] Y;
wire [3:0] state;

automatMura automatMura1(x,reset,clkKA,Y,state);

always @ (posedge clkOA) 
if (!reset) begin
case (Y) 
 3: begin 
    A <= d1; 
    B <= d2;
    end 
 12: begin
    S2 <= A << 2;
    S1 <= A^B;
    end 
 16:S3 = B >> 3; 
 96: begin
    S3 <= S1 << 3;
    S2 <= S2 + S3;
    end
 384: begin
    S1 <= B << 2;
    S3 <= S3 + S1;
    end
 512: S3 = S3 + S2;
 1024: S1 = S1 + B;
 2048: S1 = A + S1;
 4096: S1 = ~S1;
 8192: S1 = S1^S3;
 49152: begin 
    B <= B<<1;
    A <= A+B;
    end
 196608: begin
    A <= A >> 3;
    B <= B & S2;
    end
 262144: B=~B;
default: S1 = B | S1; //state=13
endcase
end
else if (reset) 
begin
    A <=0; 
    B <= 0; 
    S1 <= 0; 
    S2 <= 0; 
    S3 <= 0;
end

endmodule

module automatMura(X,reset,clk,Y,state);
input X,reset, clk;
output [19:0] Y;
output reg [3:0] state;
wire [3:0] D;
reg [3:0] Q;
always @(Q) state = Q;
assign D[0] = ~Q[0]&~Q[1] | ~Q[0]&~Q[3] | 
~Q[0]&Q[2];
assign D[1] = Q[0]&~Q[1] | ~Q[0]&Q[1]&~Q[3] | ~Q[0]&Q[1]&Q[2];
assign D[2] = ~Q[0]&Q[2] | ~Q[1]&Q[2] | Q[0]&Q[1]&~Q[2];
assign D[3] = Q[0]&~Q[2]&Q[3] | ~Q[0]&Q[2]&Q[3] | !Q[1]&Q[3] | ~Q[3]&Q[0]&Q[1]&Q[2] | ~Q[0]&Q[1]&~Q[2]&~Q[3]&~X;
assign Y[0] = ~Q[3]&~Q[2]&~Q[1]&Q[0];
assign Y[1] = ~Q[3]&~Q[2]&~Q[1]&Q[0];
assign Y[2] = ~Q[3]&~Q[2]&Q[1]&~Q[0];
assign Y[3] = ~Q[3]&~Q[2]&Q[1]&~Q[0];
assign Y[4] = ~Q[3]&~Q[2]&Q[1]&Q[0];
assign Y[5] = ~Q[3]&Q[2]&~Q[1]&~Q[0];
assign Y[6] = ~Q[3]&Q[2]&~Q[1]&~Q[0];
assign Y[7] = ~Q[3]&Q[2]&~Q[1]&Q[0];
assign Y[8] = ~Q[3]&Q[2]&~Q[1]&Q[0];
assign Y[9] = ~Q[3]&Q[2]&Q[1]&~Q[0];
assign Y[10] = ~Q[3]&Q[2]&Q[1]&Q[0];
assign Y[11] = Q[3]&~Q[2]&~Q[1]&~Q[0] | Q[3]&Q[2]&Q[1]&Q[0];
assign Y[12] = Q[3]&~Q[2]&~Q[1]&Q[0];
assign Y[13] = Q[3]&~Q[2]&Q[1]&~Q[0];
assign Y[14] = Q[3]&~Q[2]&Q[1]&Q[0];
assign Y[15] = Q[3]&~Q[2]&Q[1]&Q[0];
assign Y[16] = Q[3]&Q[2]&~Q[1]&~Q[0];
assign Y[17] = Q[3]&Q[2]&~Q[1]&~Q[0];
assign Y[18] = Q[3]&Q[2]&~Q[1]&Q[0];
assign Y[19] = Q[3]&Q[2]&Q[1]&~Q[0];
always@(posedge clk)
if(!reset) begin
Q = D;
end
else if(reset)begin
Q = 0;
end
endmodule

Testbench
`timescale 1ns/1ps
module tb_spec_dig_dev;
reg [7:0] d1, d2; 
reg reset, clkKA, clkOA;
wire x; 
wire [7:0] oA, oB, oS1, oS2, oS3; 
wire [3:0] state;

specialized_digital_device spec_dig_dev(d1, d2, reset, clkKA, clkOA, x, oA, oB, oS1, oS2, oS3, state);

initial begin
clkKA = 0; clkOA = 0; d1 = 26; d2 = 22; reset = 1;
#135 reset = 0;
#300 reset = 1;
#40 $finish;
end

always #10 clkKA = ~clkKA;
initial #5
      forever
        #10 clkOA = !clkOA;
endmodule

I attepted write this constraints, but it didn't help me
Constraints (XDC file)
set_property PACKAGE_PIN C8 [get_ports {clkKA}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN C8 [get_ports {clkOA}]

create_clock -period 15.000 -name sysclkKA -waveform {0.000 5.000} [get_ports clkKA]
create_clock -period 15.000 -name sysclkOA -waveform {0.000 5.000} [get_ports clkOA]

I'm using device xc7k70tfbg676-1 (Kintex 7 family).
Also, I found pin descriptions, what used to set right PACKAGE_PIN, for this device by link:
https://www.xilinx.com/content/dam/xilinx/support/packagefiles/k7packages/xc7k70tfbg676pkg.txt
Profs of that it don't work is waveform diagram was got as the result of Post-Implementation Function simulation where clock period equeal 10, but not 15 as in constraints.
Waveform


P.S.:
In result of Post Implementation timing simulation I'm getting same clock period (10 instead of 15, what's expected)
Result of Post Implementation timing simulation:



What is the difference between the 4 different waveform images?  What do you want us to see?  Edit all new information into the question, not here in the comments.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The test bench has the following:
always #10 clkKA = ~clkKA;

Which means during the simulation clkKA is toggled every 10 nanoseconds, which matches the behaviour shown in the simulation waveform viewer.
Whereas the create_clock used in the constraints is used to control the timing analysis of the expected clock frequency, rather than setting the actual clock frequency used in the simulation.

But in result of Post Implementation timing simulation I'm getting same clock period (10 instead of 15, what's expected)
